# Distribution of Squared Euclidean Norm of Gaussian Vector

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-normal-distribution

If $\boldsymbol{X} \sim \mathcal{N}_N(\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\Sigma})$ is an $N$-dimensional gaussian vector, where $\boldsymbol{\mu} \in  \mathbb{R}^N$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$, what is the distribution of

$$Y=\lVert X \rVert^2$$

where $Y=\lVert \cdot \rVert$ denotes the $L_2$-norm (Euclidean norm) ?

Note that following question was answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2723239). And claims that it has [generalised chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution). But I couldn't manage to find parameters. If $ Y \sim \tilde{\chi}^2(\boldsymbol{w},\boldsymbol{k},\boldsymbol{\lambda},m,s)$ How to find its parameters from $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$?

Comment: The referenced Wikipedia article is clear: you diagonalize $\Sigma$ and apply its formulas.

Comment: @whuber From wikipedia I concluded that in my case $\boldsymbol{w}$ is diagonal elements of $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$. $\boldsymbol{k}$ is vector of 1's. $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$ is elementwise square of $\boldsymbol{\mu}$. $m$ and $s$ are 0. Am I correct?

Comment: I cannot tell because you haven't told us anything about your notation.

Comment: Here are my notations: $\boldsymbol{X} \sim \mathcal{N}_N(\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\Sigma})$, $Y=\lVert X \rVert^2 \sim \tilde{\chi}^2(\boldsymbol{w},\boldsymbol{k},\boldsymbol{\lambda},m,s)$. Please suggest different notation if its more appropriate.

Comment: What I meant is that you haven't provided any details of what your values actually are, yet in your previous comment you appear to be asking us what those values might be!

Comment: If you mean parameters of generalized chi-squared, I used same notation as its used in wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

If covariance matrix is diagonal, I think parameters can be found following way:

$$\boldsymbol{w}=diag(\boldsymbol{\Sigma})$$
$$\boldsymbol{k}=[1,...,1]^T$$
$$\boldsymbol{\lambda}=(\boldsymbol{\mu} \odot \boldsymbol{\mu}) ⊘ diag(\boldsymbol{\Sigma})$$
$$m=0$$
$$s=0$$

Where  "$\odot$" and "⊘" represents elementwise product and divison respectively. And "diag" function just takes diagonal entries of a matrix as a vector.

Comment: Could you please explain your notation?

Comment: @utobi I added explanation. Is it sufficient?

Comment: In that case your formulas are nonsensical in more than one dimension, because the expression for $\lambda$ contains divisions by zero in all off-diagonal elements.  (Moreover, by comparing it to the Wikipedia article it's clearly incorrect.)